# Enable compression in Windows Azure

Tags: java, azure, compression

How to enable compression in Windows Azure?

I am trying to deploy my web application developed in **java (OfBiz) on Windows Azure Cloud**.
I am not using Apache.
I am using tomcat only.

How can I enable compression using MS Load Balancer or any other alternative?

Comment: Please take hints from the [edits to your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16558428/revisions).  People should not have to edit every post you make!

Comment: What compression are you talking about? Compression over HTTP protocol? Compression in Blob Storage account? ? ?

Comment: i want to compress the images folder. Is there any way of enabling compression for a particular folder....... say, compress all images of "hot-deploy\referral\images"